# iOS - Is there any delete message api available for the Sinch instant message

Tags: ios, sinch, instant-messaging

I have an ios application with Sinch instant message integrated in it. 
I want to provide the functionality to delete some chat history of some user.
I went through the Sinch documentation but did not find any api for delete message.

If, anybody who has worked with Sinch can help?

Comment: I have tried Sinch instant messaging but stuck in some issue can u help me>

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to delete chat messages queued for delivery.